# Huawei modem change auto answer settings

Tags: terminal, modem

Is there a way to change Huawei modem ATS0=1 command to be permanently set, so that there would not be need to send that command every time when modem is plugged in ?

On each modem-plugin command is by default ATS0=0, that means that modem auto call answer is disabled.